Добавление фото через телеграм в wordpress
Есть бот, который принимает сначала заголовок, а потом текст новости и отправляет его на сайт wordpress. Бот работает, но есть необходимость добавления фото в новости. Попробовал сделать через gpt, но его правка в коде не дала результата. Сообщение в телеграме отправляю, пробовал png, jpg, heic, но бот не реагирует на это, даже не пишет в логах ничего, будто ничего и не отправил, а реагирует только на текст. Подскажите, кто знает, как добавить рабочую функцию такую?
from telegram import Update, Bot
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackContext
import requests
    # Настройки
    TELEGRAM_TOKEN = 'token'
    WP_URL = 'https://site/wp-json/wp/v2/posts'
    WP_USER = 'pass'
    WP_PASSWORD = 'pass'
    
    # Аутентификация WordPress
    def get_wp_token():
        response = requests.post(
            f'https://site/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token',
            data={'username': WP_USER, 'password': WP_PASSWORD}
        )
        if response.status_code != 200:
            print("Ошибка аутентификации:", response.json())
            return None
        return response.json().get('token')
    
    # Обработка сообщений
    def handle_message(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
        chat_id = update.message.chat_id
        text = update.message.text
        
        if not context.user_data.get('post_title'):
            # Запоминаем заголовок
            context.user_data['post_title'] = text
            update.message.reply_text('Заголовок получен! Теперь отправьте текст новости.')
        elif not context.user_data.get('post_content'):
            # Запоминаем текст новости
            context.user_data['post_content'] = text
            publish_post(update, context)
        else:
            update.message.reply_text('Вы уже отправили заголовок и текст. Попробуйте заново!')
    
    def publish_post(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
        token = get_wp_token()
        headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'}
    
        # Отправка поста
        response = requests.post(WP_URL, headers=headers, json={
            'title': context.user_data['post_title'],
            'content': context.user_data['post_content'],
            'status': 'publish',
            'categories': [7]  # Укажи ID категории новостей
        })
    
        if response.status_code == 201:
            update.message.reply_text('Новость опубликована!')
            context.user_data.clear()  # Очищаем данные после публикации
        else:
            update.message.reply_text('Ошибка публикации. Попробуйте снова.')
    
    # Настройка бота
    def main():
        updater = Updater(TELEGRAM_TOKEN, use_context=True)
        dp = updater.dispatcher
    
        dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, handle_message))
        updater.start_polling()
        updater.idle()
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main() 


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Выкинь эту дыру, изучай АПИ ВП
